# Does the cross-sectional shape of a fuselage affect drag?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, drag, fuselage

Comparing two  bodies with the **same streamlined longitudinal shape**, and the same **cross-sectional area**, one with a **circular** cross-sectional **shape**, the other with a **quadratic** cross-sectional **shape**, which one of these two bodies would create more aerodynamic drag?

My prediction would be that it is the one with quadratic cross-sectional shape. As around the sharp edges where the two straight surfaces meet, flow interference would occur, which increases the total aerodynamic drag.

*Note that these two bodies have 0 angle of attack relative to the incoming flow.*

Related question: [Why is the fuselage on an airliner circular-shaped?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21523/why-is-the-fuselage-on-an-airliner-circular-shaped?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Related: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/1.C036032    and https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA389409.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic body has more surface area compared to the round body, so this alone will guarantee a higher friction drag.

If the angles of attack and sideslip were always zero and no lift is created, the edges would not cause trouble. But as soon as a lift-producing wing is attached, the interference will create crossflow which will result in a higher drag of the rectangular fuselage.

Comment: @MichaelHall Yes, a circle has the minimum perimeter for a given area.  Any non-circular shape (with the same cross sectional area) will therefore have more wetted area than a circular shape.

Comment: I had a momentary doubt, but mathed it out to confirm for myself.  Thanks!

Comment: Lengthwise, I was surprised to learn that the optimum fineness ratio was surprisingly stubby; 3:1 or something? The Questair Venture, the stubby little high perf kit plane, was close to egg shaped and it is supposed to have close to the ideal min drag profile.

Comment: Hi. Can you please explain how the "crossflow" would increase drag? I'm having a hard time visualizing it, thanks.

Comment: @Frank With sideslip the flow has a sideways component that must now negotiate the sharp corners of the rectangular fuselage. This will lead to separated flow on the leeward side and lower local pressure, which has a rearward component, adding to drag.

Comment: @PeterKämpf  I understand how this may happen in a sideslip. But in the answer you said the attachment of a lift-producing wing will cause interference that creates crossflow and add to drag. Does wing-fuselage interference have association with crossflow and drag? If so, how?

Comment: @Frank The wing produces upwash ahead and downwash aft of it which locally acts much like the crossflow in a sideslip. At zero angle of attack this does not cause much drag, but when the fuselage is inclined, this adds a bit of drag, too.

Comment: @PeterKämpf  Oh, so upwash and downwash don’t simply end at the wingroot, but extend a bit inboard, and have some effect on the fuselage. Is that correct? I believe the additional drag by this effect would be fairly small then.

Comment: @Frank correct.